# Alarm Clock iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, clock, alarm

I am developing an application of Alarm Clock. How can I pass the selected audio file from the device to the local notification ?

Note : I am using MPMediaPickerController to pick the song from iPod Music Library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't play an iPod song with a push notification.

The [`sound` property of a push notification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1) references a file *within your application bundle*. That is, it's a file that your app must provide (inside your bundle, so copying/downloading into your app's Documents directory doesn't work either). See also [Preparing Custom Alert Sounds](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW6).

Also, note that there is an upper length of the sound to be played:

> Custom sounds must be under 30 seconds when played. If a custom sound is over that limit, the default system sound is played instead.

Comment: what would be a way to make a mp3 alarm clock then because an alarm clock app 'Night Stand' is able to do that, there the link for the app http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/night-stand-hd-alarm-clock/id364657045?mt=8

Comment: @SeungUnHam: The app has to run at the moment the alarm rings for that. Either in foreground, maybe even in background, but it has to be running and then it's simply about playing a sound, not about push notifications any more. All those fancy clocks also are only visible if the app is in the foreground and the screen is not locked.

Comment: I understand that they are merely heightening a muted mp3 that was playing for the alarm. Now, I wonder how they call the function that heightens the volume of the music while the device is sleeping (locked)(power button pressed). P.S. the mp3 alarm doesn't work if the application is in background(home button pressed) before the device is locked but it works when the iphone is on the foreground right before the device gets locked.

Answer (score 1):

Dark dust is right you cant use a song for your alarm you must need to use a compress sound .aif, .wav or file format which having sound in compressed format.

and you cant set from a library you can set only by programatically. Basically alarm is used with local notification so you need to use some thing like this.

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (localNotif == nil)
        return;
    localNotif.fireDate = itemDate;
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    localNotif.alertBody = @"Please add reaction with your meal";
    // Set the action button
    localNotif.alertAction = @"View";


    localNotif.soundName = @"Iphone_Alarm.aif";
    //localNotif.soundName=@"sound.mp3";  // you cant use mp3 format
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;


    // Schedule the notification
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
    [localNotif release];
```

Comment: 'Night Stand' app supports library mp3 alarm do you have any clue how to make that?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to assign a song from the device library to the local notification. 
However, you can copy it in you app's Documents Directory and then assign it, and eventually, when the notification is fired or app is launching (you decide) you can delete that song from the app Documents if it is not needed anymore.

Comment: It is not possible to assign a sound from document directory even.